# Disable password in WIx Installer

Tags: wix

I have a installer project which is developed in Wix.
I have the below code with util:xmlconfig

```
<util:XmlConfig 
                  Id="xml.SetMYPassword"
                  Action="create"
                  ElementPath="/configuration/DataReport/Password"
                  Node="value"      
                  Value="[MY_PASSWORD]"
                  File="[#MyService]"
                  On="install"
                  PreserveModifiedDate="yes"
                  Sequence="1" />
```

Now the issue is, when I am installing the package the password is shown like "myPassword" instead of ******. How can we change the above code such that the password should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to stop the MY_PASSWORD property from appearing in the log you should set the hidden attribute to yes in its declaration.

```
<Property Id="MY_PASSWORD" Hidden="yes" Secure="yes" />
```

Note that the util:XmlConfig custom action may still display this in its own internal logging.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply and information. But I don't want to show the password in util:XmlConfig as well. Is the <Property Id="MY_PASSWORD" Hidden="yes" Secure="yes" /> works for the same? Please let me know.

Comment: I don't use XMLConfig at the moment, so I can't easily test it.
Try it and report back, it may work, but the default for custom actions is to wrap all parameters together in a string to be passed to the action which is logged. If that is the case then you may need to write a secure version of XML config yourself, or join the wix team and fix the issue yourself.